# Passing function pointer in a struct with pthreads

Tags: c, linux, pthreads, posix

I am trying to emulate a callback mechanism in C with pthreads. The code I have is below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

struct fopen_struct {
  char *filename;
  char *mode;
  void *(*callback) (FILE *);
};

void *fopen_callback(FILE *);
void fopen_t(void *(*callback)(FILE *), const char *, const char *);
void *__fopen_t__(void *);

void fopen_t(void *(*callback)(FILE *), const char *filename, const char *mode) {
  struct fopen_struct args;
  args.filename = filename;
  args.mode = mode;
  args.callback = callback;
  pthread_t thread;
  pthread_create(&thread, NULL, &__fopen_t__, &args);
}

void *__fopen_t__(void *ptr) {
  struct fopen_struct *args = (struct fopen_struct *)ptr;
  FILE *result = fopen(args -> filename, args -> mode);
  args -> callback(result);
}

int main() {
  fopen_t(&fopen_callback, "test.txt", "r");
}

void *fopen_callback(FILE *stream) {
  if (stream != NULL)
    printf("Opened file successfully\n");
  else
    printf("Error\n");
}
```

This compiles, but when executing, it completes without an error or message on screen. What am I missing?

Comment: Your main thread finishes prematurally.

Comment: It sounds a bit heavy to spawn a thread just to run one callback. If I were you, I would have created a thread dedicated to the callback execution. When a callback is needed, you could push it to a queue that would be processed by the callback thread. Of course if the work done by the callback is too large (but it should not), spawning a thread for it is ok :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `main` thread is exiting before completion of `__fopen_t__`. So either detach that thread(**fopen_t**) using `pthread_detach` and do other useful stuff or wait for the completion of `__fopen_t__` using `pthread_join`.

When using `pthread_join`, your `fopen_t` may look like,

```
void fopen_t(void *(*callback)(FILE *), const char *filename, const char *mode)
{
    struct fopen_struct args;
    args.filename = filename;
    args.mode = mode;
    args.callback = callback;
    pthread_t thread;
    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, &__fopen_t__, &args);
    pthread_join( thread, NULL );   // Waiting till the new thread completes
}
```

Refer man pages [pthread_detach](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/pthread_detach/) and [pthread_join](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/pthread_join/) for more details.

---

To be more logical as per R..'s comment, the code with dynamic allocation is given below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct fopen_struct {
    char *filename;
    char *mode;
    void *(*callback) (FILE *);
};

void *fopen_callback(FILE *);
pthread_t* fopen_t(void *(*callback)(FILE *), const char *, const char *);
void *__fopen_t__(void *);

// returns pthread_t* to be freed by caller
pthread_t* fopen_t(void *(*callback)(FILE *), const char *filename, const char *mode)
{

    struct fopen_struct *args = calloc( 1, sizeof(  struct fopen_struct ) );
    args->filename = filename;
    args->mode = mode;
    args->callback = callback;

    pthread_t *thread = calloc( 1, sizeof( pthread_t ) );   // Need error checks
    pthread_create( thread, NULL, &__fopen_t__, args);
    //pthread_join( thread, NULL ); // `thread` is returned to caller

    return thread;
}

// takes `struct fopen_struct*` as argument and will be freed
void *__fopen_t__(void *ptr) {
    struct fopen_struct *args = (struct fopen_struct *)ptr;
    FILE *result = fopen(args -> filename, args -> mode);
    args -> callback(result);

    free( args ); args = NULL;
    return NULL;
}

int main() {
    pthread_t *th_id = NULL;

    th_id = fopen_t(&fopen_callback, "test.txt", "r");      // Need error checks
    pthread_join( *th_id, NULL );  // Wait till the __fopen_t__ thread finishes
    free( th_id ); th_id = NULL;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't think `fopen_t` is supposed to wait for the thread to finish; the whole point is that it can run asynchronously. Instead, `fopen_t` should *return* the `pthread_t` so the caller can later wait for the result (join it).

Comment: @R..thanks and the same is updated in the answer. Please free to modify the above answer if needed

Answer (score 0):

Add `sleep()` in the bottom of main. Maybe your program finished before getting result.

**ADDITIONAL COMMENT**

This is simplest way to notice this bug, But not correct way. :)

Comment: I don't think sleeping is a nice way to syncronise different threads.

Comment: Yes, I know. This is simplest way that @sankha-narayan-guria notice his bug.

Comment: Yes it's an easy way to notice the bug, but it's a very harmful recommendation for someone new to threads. Unless they has some magical innate understanding of synchronization, new thread programmers are likely to adopt this practice as a substitute for proper synchronization, which it is not.